# Where to include jaxb.properties file?

Tags: properties, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I have REST (Jersey) webservice that makes use of some data objects that are marshalled/unmarshalled to/from XML.  The data objects are in a separate project/jar that the webservice war depends on.

I'm using MOXy as my JAXB implementation since I'm deploying to Glassfish and that's already included.  I know I need a jaxb.properties file to set the JAXB implementation to MOXy with this entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

The question is, should the jaxb.properties file be included in the data object jar or in the webservice war or both?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You package the jaxb.properties file with your model classes.  GlassFish does not include the MOXy bundle yet, but you can add it easily.  Check out my blog for more info:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html

Comment: What if my model classes are spread in more than one directory? Do I need to place one `jaxb.properties` files in each folder?

Comment: Yes: "JAXB Providers must generate a jaxb.properties file in each package containing schema derived classes."

Answer (score 30):

If you don't want or can not use the jaxb.properties (you have a lot of package, the model is in a external jar, you want only java and no configuration files...), you can directly specify the JaxbContextFactory :

Do not create the context using :

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{Person.class, ObjectFactory.class}, properties);
```

But instead, specify the factory to use :

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[]{Person.class, ObjectFactory.class}, properties);
```

where the factory is :

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;
```

It is exactly the same, but it is specified explicitly in the java code instead of implicitly in a configuration file.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot.

Comment: Thanks.It helped to resolve one of my critical issue.

Comment: I prefer this solution to the jax.properties file which is ignored by maven during test runs (at least for me). jc = JAXBContextFactory.createContext("com.mymodels", null) did the trick for me.

Comment: This is much more straightforward than not only other answers in this question, but many other questions as well. Thanks a lot!