# JAXB returns "null" string instead of null

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

on setting an element:

```
element.setValue(null)
```

it marshalls the XML to

```
<element>
 <value>null<value>
</element>
```

I am expecting it to be:

```
<element>
  <value/>
</element>
```

or

```
 <element />
```

Comment: Can you show the class of `element`? In particular how the `value` property is annotated (if at all).

Comment: value is of type xsd:String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAXB does not marshal a null value as:

```
<foo>null</foo>
```

By default it will not marshal the element.  If you annotate it with `@XmlElement(nillable=true)` the `xsi:nil` attribute will be used.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html

Comment: This is correct. There must be some problem with my logic. JAXB does not create String "null".

Answer (score 0):

You need to put  @XmlValue annotation on getter method value

```
@XmlValue
public String getValue(){
}
```

further see [How to represent null value as empty element with JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743306/how-to-represent-null-value-as-empty-element-with-jaxb)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set to **element.setValue("")** , instead of null directly for the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. set the value with an empty string and do that each time you want an empty field in the file
2. In the getter method of value you do so:

   ```
   public String getValue(){
    if(value == null)
          return null;
    return value;
   }
   ```

   In this case if you don't give a value to this field then you will have an empty element.
   Personnally, I prefer the first solution