# How to marshall null fields in Jersey JAX-RS implementation?

Tags: java, json, jersey, moxy

In a Glassfish/Jersey JAX-RS web application, how can I instruct the JSON provider (which defaults to MOXy in Jersey 2.22) to marshall null fields with JSON `null` value instead of skip them?
I understand the use of `@XmlElement(nillable = true)`, but since I need it for all classes fields it would be quite cumbersome to add it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MOXy `@XmlNullPolicy`:

```java
@XmlNullPolicy(emptyNodeRepresentsNull = true, nullRepresentationForXml = XmlMarshalNullRepresentation.EMPTY_NODE)
```

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11748678/1986499 (Option #2)

Comment: Do I need to add @XmlNullPolicy to all fields/classes? I'm looking for a configuration option to set this behaviour globally.

Comment: I don't know any option like that.