# javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: eclipselink.media-type value: application/json

Tags: java, json, spring, jaxb

I work on a project, made with Spring Framework, where i want to use JaxB, to convert an object to json, and i recieve this error:

```
javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: eclipselink.media-type value: application/json
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.setProperty(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.setProperty(Unknown Source)
at com.fabbydesign.controller.DashboardController.main(DashboardController.java:82)
```

The code that i test is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{

    ReturnBean rb = new ReturnBean();
    rb.setStatus(1);
    rb.setMessage("Message here!");

    JAXBContext jc;
    try {
        jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ReturnBean.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        marshaller.marshal(rb, System.out);

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have added in pom.xml EclipseLink dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

and, i have added the file `jaxb.properties` with the content:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

I don't know why i still recieve this error, because, as i read on this forum i think i did all.
What i want to mention, is, that the code that i test is in the directory:

```
src\main\java\com\fabbydesign\controller
```

and the file `jaxb.properties` is in the directory:

```
src\main\resources\com\fabbydesign\controller
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Simple, you can specify system variable like:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.bind.context.factory", "org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory");
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

i found the problem: i had to add jaxb.properties in the package where ReturnBean class is located !!!

Comment: that's what I meant with my answer above. The location of the jaxb.properties was wrong. good, you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the location of the jaxb.properties file is correct. The stacktrace still contains com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime classes, which indicates that the wrong factory class is still being used.

have a look here for more info or alternative way to setup the factory: [Where to include jaxb.properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340625/where-to-include-jaxb-properties-file)